# Search a number in string formatted array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

My array looks like this:

```
array( '0|500|0.50', '501|1000|0.75' );
```

I am trying to run a search to get the KEY which has the searched value.

I made this function to search:

```
function cu_array_search($str,$array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(strstr($str,$value)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and using it like this when checking:

```
if (cu_array_search(500,$array) {
```

but it never return true, despite that 500 exists in first key in array .

How to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strpos` will make you function return true even that's `0.5001` but not `500`.

You should explode the value by `|`, then check whether the number in the array.

```
function cu_array_search($num, $array){
  return count(array_filter($array, function ($var) use ($num) {
    return in_array($num, explode('|', $var));
  })) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The haystack is the first argument, not the second:

```
if(strstr($value,$str)) {
```

Additionally, `strpos` is faster at this, so you should use:

```
function cu_array_search($str,$array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(strpos($value,$str) !== false) {
            return $key;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AhmedFouad You should use xdazz's solution, there are cases where string searching might retrieve incorrect results for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

First, `strstr` parameters are wrong

Second, `return false` should be at the end of the loop.

Third, If you need KEY then You need to use `return $key` instead of `return true`

```
function cu_array_search($str,$array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(strstr($value, $str)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
<?php

function cu_array_search($str, $array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $temp_array=explode('|', $value);
        if (in_array($str, $temp_array))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$array = array( '0|500|0.50', '501|1000|0.75' );


if (cu_array_search(500, $array))
    echo "success";
else
    echo "failed" ;

?>
```